# List / Scan for available WiFis iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, wifi, network-scan

I'm searching for a way to present available WiFis in an iPhone App.
So far my research resulted in the following:

- Apps that implement(ed) such a functionality were removed from the AppStore (means you can't deploy the App via AppStore which is fine for me)
- Apple hides the functionality that is necessary for a scan in a private framework and you can't find any explanations/comments/examples on "how to use"
- http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless seems to be most promising. anyway, i can't figure out how to include the delivered sources in my code so that it runs on a device

Even the adaptions that are mentioned htt ://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/issues/detail?id=26 didn't get me the desired results. The most progress was ending up with a

> dlopen error: dlopen(/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/Aeropuerto.bundle/Aeropuerto, 1): image not found
> failed: __Apple80211Associate

message after launching the app on a device (iPhone 3GS; iOS 3.1.3).

Used source code that procudes the error is here:

```
NSMutableDictionary *networks;
bool scanning;
void *libHandle;
void *airportHandle;
int (*open)(void *);
int (*bind)(void *, NSString *);
int (*close)(void *);
int (*scan)(void *, NSArray **, void *);

networks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences", RTLD_LAZY);
// libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Preferences", RTLD_LAZY);
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager", RTLD_LAZY);

open = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");
bind = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
close = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Close");
scan = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Scan");

open(&airportHandle);
bind(airportHandle, @"en0");

NSLog(@"Scanning...");
scanning = true;
NSArray *scan_networks;
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
scan(airportHandle, &scan_networks, parameters);
bool changed;
for (int i = 0; i < [scan_networks count]; i++) {
    if([networks objectForKey:[[scan_networks objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey:@"BSSID"]] != nil 
       && ![[networks objectForKey:[[scan_networks objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey:@"BSSID"]] isEqualToDictionary:[scan_networks objectAtIndex: i]])
        changed = true;
    [networks setObject:[scan_networks objectAtIndex: i] forKey:[[scan_networks objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey:@"BSSID"]];
}
if(changed) {
    NSLog(@"NetworksUpdated");
}
scanning = false;
NSLog(@"Scan Finished...");
NSLog(@"Found %i networks: %@", [networks count], networks);
```

Even if trying one of the other commented lines, it doesn't work:
program received EXC_BAD_ACCESS and several

> warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
>
> warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.

What i'm searching are hints how to include iphone-wireless in my project and how to modify the given code?
An alternative would be a tip on how to scan for WiFis in your environment.

Would be nice if someone could help.

Comment: just tried it out: though the code warns me during runtime; it prints out found WiFis. There must be a better approach than this buggy one? Would be nice at least properly open and close the access to the WiFi-hardware (which doesn't seem to work with the above code) 0o

Answer (score 1):

path has changed in 3.X and beyond, from :

```
/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/Aeropuerto.bundle/Aeropuerto
```

to:

```
/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfifuration
```